# Install: can not Mount filesytem.squashfs

Tags: system-installation, iso

I'm trying to install Ubuntu for the first time and since my PC doesn't support boot from USB, I've trying to install(dualboot) Ubuntu 14.04LTS. I have the iso(64bit) burned as image to a DVD+R using Win7 default Burn Disc Image feature.

When I restart my windows 7 PC, I see Ubuntu logo come up, then it goes black as says something like: "Can not mount filesystem.squashfs on // filesystem.squashfs".

I have no idea what that means.

PC Specs FYI
Athlon II X2 2.7GHZ
4GB Ram
Over 400GB Hardrive Space Available

Please advise.

Comment: Did you see the GRUB menu at the beginning? Have you [checked the md5-sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) of your DVD? You can try the [Minimal install CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)

Comment: No GRUB Menu, MD5Sum was correct(before burned, can't figure out how to check it on disk). Have not tried minimal install CD(I have no CDs, I just went out and bought DVDs).

Comment: @Xubu-Tur I had already stated that I cannot boot from USB. I did try that already.

Comment: Hmm [Wubi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_%28Ubuntu_installer%29) is another option (with limitations) or you burn a Minimal-Disc on DVD and try again... Or perhaps a full iso with a 32bit version...

Comment: I kept trying and it finally installed.